# 2D and 3D Client Side Design on Website

Tags: c#, sql, webgl

I would like to integrate a 2D and 3D floor plan designer for my customers on my asp.net website.  I have looked at WebGL.  Has anyone used WebGL for doing website floor plan design?  Or can you recommend a different API/Toolkit, etc?  I am new to 2D and 3D design so any tutorials would be great.

My goal is for customers to be able to design their home on the website then add security cameras to show coverage and placement.

I also want to be able to use C# code behind to access the sql database to get product information.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This question is way too broad for this site. Please take a look at the help pages and see what's acceptable here, how to ask and what you need to show you've done. As it stands, this question will probably be closed soon, which would be a shame for you.

Comment: This question is off topic for stack overflow. you might want to try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/